# Replace double backslash in Pandas csv file

Tags: python, pandas

Python 3.9.5/Pandas 1.1.3

I have a very large csv file with values that look like:

`Ac\\Nme Products Inc.`

and all the values are different company names with double backslashes in random places throughout.

I'm attempting to get rid of all the double backslashes.  It's not working in Pandas. But a simple test against the standalone value just using `string.replace` does work.

Example:

```
org = "Ac\\Nme Products Inc."
result = org.replace("\\","")
print(result)
```

returns `AcNme Products Inc.` as the output, as I would expect.

However, using Pandas with the names in a csv file:

```
import pandas as pd
csv_input = pd.read_csv('/Users/me/file.csv')
csv_input.replace("\\", "")
csv_input.to_csv('/Users/me/file_revised.csv', index=False)
```

When I open the new `file_revised.csv` file, the value still shows as `Ac\\Nme Products Inc.`

**EDIT 1:**

Here is a snippet of `file.csv` as requested:

```
id,company_name,address,country  1000566,A1 Comm\\Nodity Traders,LEVEL 28 THREE PACIFIC PLACE 1 QUEEN'S RD EAST HK,TH 1000579,"A2 A Mf\\g. Co., Ltd.",53 YONG-AN 2ND ST. TAINAN TAIWAN,CA 1000585,"A2 Z Logisitcs Indi\\Na Pvt., Ltd.",114A/1 1ST FLOOR SOUTH RAJA ST TUTICORIN - 628 001 TAMILNADU - INDIA,PE
```

Comment: This really looks like an encoding problem, which encoding is the file?

Comment: does it affect all string columns? Are all columns strings?

Comment: @NicolasMartinez `{'encoding': 'ascii', 'confidence': 1.0, 'language': ''}`

Comment: can you post an snippet of the file?

Comment: @Marat yes it affects all string columns, and no not all columns are strings.  One column is int, the rest are strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas doesn't have a dataframe level string operation, but it can be updated per-column:

```
for col in csv_input.columns:
    if col == 'that_int_column':
        continue
    csv_input[col] = csv_input[col].str.replace(r"\\N", "")
```

Comment: This works! Just FYI, I do get a warning: `FutureWarning: The default value of regex will change from True to False in a future version.`